# Content in UIScrollView is being cutoff early

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview, uiscrollview

I have several `UIViews` within a`UIScrollView` and I want them to scroll all the way to the bottom of the `UIScrollView` before cutting off (See Image #2).

Background on the scroll view:

I created the `UIScrollView` itself is a subclass of a custom`UIView`.  I put the view in a `UIScrollView` so the auto layout in storyboard creates the correct frame for the device.

In the view controller attached to the storyboard `UIViewController` I created an`IBOutlet` to the`UIView`, and in the `viewDidAppear` function I called a function attached to the view that populated the `UIScrollView`.

In the storyboard I gave the view a blue background so I could tell its frame.  Here is the what the storyboard looks like: [image]

Then this is what it looks like on my phone:[image: phone view]

Notice how much space exists between where the view cuts off and where the bottom of the screen is.  It does this on all devices.

I have tried adjusting the bottom content inset.  It is currently at 0.0 but I tried to make it -20 and that did not help.

How can I fix this?

Comment: increase the size of UIView in the scrollView ... apply constraints of the view to the parent as all trailing leading top and bottom align

Comment: it turns out that I called set the frame of the scroll view before the constraints had been applied to the view so it was the size of what had been in storyboard.